# Unanswered is not the same as "no answers"?

Tags: discussion, support, unanswered-questions

I see this link for "unanswered":

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript

but the listing has questions that are answered...

I have to further click a tab "no answers" to see:

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript?tab=noanswers

for the questions that really have no answer.

So "unanswered" is not the same as "no answers"?