# "Unanswered" option to the new custom question filter

Tags: feature-request, bug, questions, unanswered-questions, filtering

Currently the new (and nice) new [question filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement?cb=1) has 3 option to choose filter:

- No answer
- No accepted answer
- Has bounty

As one can see here:

[image]

As can see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321625/unanswered-is-not-the-same-as-no-answers) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292013/the-unanswered-tab-has-multiple-answered-questions), "Unanswered" is not the same as "No answers". In addition, "Unanswered" is not the same as "No accepted answer" as "No accepted answer" will include question who has answer with positive score (but not accepted) and it will no show in "Unanswered".

As this option is part of the regular filter option I think we should line it up 
 - this may come to be handy to people like me who using this field in their regular filter:

[image]

Can we add "Unanswered" to the new question filter?

**Edit**

Just saw the "No accepted answer" filter is returning only question as "Unanswered" - it change it behavior sometime in the last couple of days... (as if I choose it for the filter I don't see question who has answer with positive score 
 even when that answer is not accepted)

So now also the **name is not fine** which makes it a bug :(

Comment: Isn't "Unanswered" equal to "no accepted answer", or am I mistaken?

Comment: @VLAZ no - "no accepted answer" will include question who has answer with positive score (but not accepted) and it will no show in "Unanswered"

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought it only showed either lack of answers or no accepted answers. Honestly, that made so much sense to me that I'm not sure I like how it actually works. So, if a question has a single answer with one upvote then that's considered "enough"? Surely a *better* answer might be needed or merely an *alternative*. Or even a *complimentary* answer that might delve deeper than the previous in some aspect. I feel that a good question deserves more than one good answers. If a question is resolved with a single answer with one upvote, then that seems like a menial task.

Comment: Maybe - this issue was discussed at log - and I must say I somehow agree with you. But, when having the current definition then I want it to be added to the filter as well

Comment: Related - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement?cb=1#comment1077885_330366 for an explanation on the current available feature. It's currently both badly labeled and lacking the very useful "no accepted answer *only*" feature.