# Filter URL is confusing after using new custom filter

Tags: bug, questions, filtering, search-box

I'm using the new customization feature for searching. When I checked some tags and the "No accepted answer" checkbox in the new question filter I and redirected to

> "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php%20arrays?sort=Newest&filters=NoAcceptedAnswer&edited=true"

(and get "Unanswered" question actual filter - but that another [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386854/unanswered-option-to-the-new-custom-question-filter))

However, when I refresh the search using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the search-box I am redirected to:

> "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+arrays"

But the questions list us **unchanged** and I still has only "Unanswered" questions.

I can also verify it because I see the "unanswered" text as:

[image]

Should I see this "unanswered" filter in the URL? is this the expected behavior?

**Edit**: this happens to me on win8.1 on chrome version: 75.0.3770.100.
One can see @meyi comment on other browser it is not reproduce. Feel free to comment/edit with more problematic OS and browser version this happens

Comment: No repro in FF 68 on Win10

Comment: On Windows (10.0.17763): No reproducing on Firefox Nightly (70.0a1), Microsoft Edge (44.17763.1.0), Internet Explorer (11.557.17763.0), Chromium (77.0.3856.0), or Microsoft Edge (77.0.221.0 canary). I did get the bug on Google Chrome (75.0.3770.142) however.